# Getting all the redirects from a url in php

Tags: php, redirect, curl, header

I have a url that redirects to multiple 302 redirects on different servers

example:
url->A->C

when url redirects to server A ,At server "A" 2 different links are generated like A1 & A2.  A2 is generated after a time period of approx 1 min on server A after A1 redirects to C(the final destination)

tried to get all the headers using:

```
print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
```

Tried :

```
$resource = fopen( $url, 'r' );
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data( $resource );
$metadata = $metadata['wrapper_data'];
```

still not able to receive headers of A2.

How can i get the location header for A2?

I can provide the headers of A1,A2,C if required

Comment: If you have access to the code, just look in the code and see what it does. You could also use the network monitor in the webmaster tools of your browser (F12).

Comment: I read the question twice and still didn't quite understand it. Especially what do you mean at _At server a 2 different links are generated simultaneously like a1 & a2_. Can you add some more code please?